# Enable/Disable another form WITHOUT INSTANTIATING NEW ONE

Tags: c#, winforms

Here's my question.. From form 1, i want when the user clicked on update items, Form 2 will open but form 1 will still remain open. At this point, I want the Form 1 to be enabled false and I've done it. But I want when the form 2 closes, the form 1 enable should be true again. I cannot do this... Here's my code:

In Form 1:

```
private void btnEditItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Form3 form3 = new Form3();
    form3.Show();
    this.Enabled = false;

}
```

In Form 2(which is for update items, after updating):

```
private void Form3_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            form1Here.Enabled = true;
        }
```

In this situation, it will open another Form1. The question is, how am i suppose to "ENABLE BACK AGAIN THE FORM 1 WITHOUT OPENING IT?" HELP ME PLEASE PROVIDE SOME SAMPLE IF POSSIBLE. THANKS

Comment: You may attach an handler to form2.FormClosed or use ShowDialog() instead of Show(),  if applicable

Comment: Why not call `form2` as modal using `form2.ShowDialog()`. This way form1 satys open but is not usable until form2 closes. Btw.: what is `Form3`? Please be concise with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a handler to your form.

```
Form3 form3 = new Form3();
form3.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(frm3_FormClosed);
form3.Show();

private void frm3_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Enabled = true;
}
```

Or you can use `ShowDialog`

> Opens a window and returns only when the newly opened window is closed.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems you want a modal Dialog Box.

From [MSDN Modal and Modeless Dialog Boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263470(v=vs.60).aspx):

> A modal dialog box must be closed (hidden or unloaded) before you can
>   continue working with the rest of the application

This means that if Form 1 opens Form 2 as a modal dialog box, form 1 will remain visible, but it is disabled, you can't do anything with it until you've closed form 2. In your words: "form 1 is disabled and when form 2 closes form 1 is enabled again".

The code:

```
private void btnEditItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Form3 form3 = new Form3()}
    {
        var dlgResult = form3.ShowDialog(); // show form 3 as a modal dialog box
        // halt this procedure until form3 is closed
        // handle the result of form3:
        if (dlgResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var x = form3.SomePropery;
            ProcessDialogOutput(x);
        }
    }
}
```

The using statement is not necessary, but it is neat programming, because Form3 implements IDisposable